# How to keep field value unchanged when foreign key object updated in Django - Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

Currently im working on an Ecommerce project in Django where i have a Order model which has Foreign key relation with Product. So all the product details are fetched from product model. Now im facing issue with the same. Whenever I make any change to Product object its getting updated in all the related Order objects too even for orders placed in past.

Is it possible to keep past order's product values unchanged  whenever Product object is updated in future? Please help. Below are the codes for your reference.

**Product Model**

```
class Product(models.Model):
measurement_choices = (('Liter', 'Liter'), ('Kilogram', 'Kilogram'), ('Cloth', 'Cloth'), 
('Shoe', 'Shoe'))
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
sku = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
stock = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
measurement = models.CharField(choices=measurement_choices, max_length=20, null=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
discounted_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', default='product.png', null=True, 
blank=True)
image_one = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
image_two = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
image_three = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
image_four = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
image_five = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/images', null=True, blank=True)
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
sub_category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
null=True,related_name='+')
status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=(('Active', 'Active'), ('Inactive', 
'Inactive')))
brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand,on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=True, null=True)
offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
color = models.ForeignKey(Color , blank=True, null=True , on_delete=models.PROTECT)
size_type = models.ForeignKey(Size , blank=True, null=True , on_delete=models.PROTECT)
history = HistoricalRecords()
```

**Order Model**

```
class Order(models.Model):
order_status = (('Pending', 'Pending'), ('Under Process', 'Under Process'), ('Dispatched', 
'Dispatched'),
                ('Delivered', 'Delivered'), ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled'), ('Out for delivery', 
'Out for delivery'))
customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(ShippingAddress, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, 
blank=True)
order_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
order_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, null=True)
status = models.CharField(choices=order_status, default='Pending', max_length=30)
payment_status = models.CharField(choices=(('Received', 'Received'), ('Failed', 'Failed'), 
('Pending', 'Pending')),
                                  default='Pending', max_length=30)
ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
# Payment details captured from payment gateway
payment_order_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True) # razorpay order id
payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True) # Razorpay payment id
payment_signature = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)# razorpay paymnet signature
payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
history = HistoricalRecords()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few options for you here if I understand your question correctly.

1. Either you can serialize the actual product details when saving the order. This could be done by using [Django serialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/serialization/) and then storing this serialized product on the order with a [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField). This way you'll keep the state for a product if you want to display or use the data later.
2. Another way would be to store a new product with a version ID, instead of updating your old products. This could be done by hooking on the pre save, creating a new version and blocking the saving of the old model. This way you'll store and can reuse the model in your templates. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/
3. The last idea would be to use a historical model insert, such as [django-simple-history](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). This would handle changes and updates for you, but you'll have to relate to a given history instance.

Comment: I tried saving serialized data in JsonField and its working but im getting difficulties while accessing those data in Template. please help